# How to correctly write the migration command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add an array field to my table. Normally, I should have done this the first time I created the table:

```
t.string :names, array: true, default: []
```

Now that I have already run the migration, could you please provide me the migration command to add this field to my Recipe table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've already run the migration, it's a better technique to create a new migration to append the new column on to the table, instead of re-running the existing migration to avoid problems with other developers (even though this may not be a concern of yours right now):

`rails g migration add_names_to_recipes names:string`

Find the newly-created migration and append the following to the relevant column:

```
class AddNamesToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :recipes, :names, :string, array: true
  end
end
```

Finally, run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

```
add_column :names, array: true, default: []
```

Comment: then run "rake db:migrate".  Does this answer your question?